# How do I get shell_exec() to change the environment before running a python script

Tags: python, php, linux

I created a virtual environment inside the **www/mysite/venv** folder and have a python script inside the folder that I'm trying to execute from the web browser. The PHP function I'm using is shell_exec().

```
<?php
shell_exec("source /home/www/mysite/venv/activate");
shell_exec("python3 /home/www/mysite/venv/python-script.py");
?>
```

The second line in the script runs but doesn't work properly because the required pip libraries are in the virtual environment and the environment does not get activate

**I've also tried:**

- /bin/bash/source
- /bin/sh/source
- source bin/activate

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the path to the python executable for your virtual environment (like `~/.venv/path/to/python` or something similar). You can find out when your python venv is active, just do a `which python3` to see it.

Comment: That doesnt work because while I do not activate the virtual environment it still runs /usr/bin/python even though I am in the venv/bin/ folder. When I try  /.var/www/vhosts/my-website/httpdocs/venv/bin/python3 is returns: sh: 1:  /.var/www/vhosts/my-website/httpdocs/venv/bin/python: not found

Comment: Ok after reading this comment a few times and trying again I figured it out and then your comment made sense.

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec("/home/www/mysite/venv/bin/python3 /home/www/mysite/venv/python-script.py"); worked without having to activate the virtual environment. I had to give the full path to the python version installed in the venv and the full path to the location of the script

Comment: you should probably just activate the environment. So something like `source /home/www/mysite/venv/activate && python3 /home/www/mysite/venv/python-script.py`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).